# Incorporate results of a Twitter search into a list

Tags: search, list, twitter

I have a list that includes members who talk about a keyword extensively. I would like to extend the scope of this list and have it update with results whenever someone mentions that keyword across Twitter (and who is not necessarily a member of the group).

Is there some way I can include the results of a Twitter keyword search into an existing Twitter list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Twitter List is for enlisting users, they may talk about anything. It's not for enlisting tweets regarding a certain topic. You can build a bot to add people, who tweets on that topic, to the list. But that doesn't ensure that, those people will keep talking about it, and so they, to some extent, might spam your list.

Twitter gives you a scope to follow a topic either with the help of a hashtag or by saving a search. You can search once for that topic and then save the search for those keywords and later on keep checking the search.